# Flexbox / Expanding height due to nested element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a deeply nested element that grows and I am trying to use flexbox to make its outer container accommodate its height. Trying to get the "orange" element to stretch vertically to include the inner most text in following pen: https://codepen.io/cssbog/pen/KKzgxgd

```
    <ol class="menu-item-list">
  <li id="menu-item-las-powr" class="menu-item control-slider active">
    <div class="label">Label</div>
    <div class="value">
      <div class="slider-view"> 
        <div class="slider-box">
          <div class="safe-slider">    
            <div class="slider-val-line-parent">
              <div class="slider-val-text">
                BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**
As I already said in the comment. You cannot change the height of the elements independently they are all in a parent-child-relationship.

You should consider using less markup and maybe use a different approach to achieve the same. If it is about the styling you could make `.value` growing with the `.slider-val-text` and use an independent `absolute` element to draw over the `.slider-val-text` (you just have to add enough padding and draw over it at the top there for this greenish box background).

However, you can set a fixed height to the `.value` container. Try `height: 168px`. The problem with that is, that it will not change depending on the text you put in in `.slider-val-text`.

You could use javascript and set the height of the `.value` container based on the height of the `.slider-val-text` once the DOM has finished loading.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const childHeight = document.querySelector('.slider-val-text').offsetHeight;
  const parent = document.querySelector('.value');
  let verticalPadding = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(parent, null).getPropertyValue('padding-top'));
  verticalPadding += parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(parent, null).getPropertyValue('padding-bottom'));
  parent.style.height = childHeight + verticalPadding + 'px';
});
```

```css
.menu-item-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  left: 1em;
  right: 40%;
}

.menu-item-list li {
  display: flex;
}

.menu-item-list .control-slider .value {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* ADDED */
  padding: 0 1em 0 0;
}

.menu-item-list .control-slider .slider-view {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.menu-item-list .control-slider .slider-view .slider-val-line-parent {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  /*position: absolute; REMOVED */
  left: 0;
}

.menu-item-list .control-slider .slider-view .slider-val-line-parent .slider-val-text {
  flex: 1;
  /* width: calc(100% + 16px); REMOVED */
  /*right: 7px;
  position: relative;
  top: 36px; REMOVED */
  padding-top: 36px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  justify-content: right;
}

.menu-item-list .control-slider .slider-box {
  height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.1em 0.25em;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: purple;
  opacity: 50%;
}

.menu-item-list .control-slider .slider-box .safe-slider {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-item-list .control-slider .slider-box .safe-slider .slider-val-line-parent {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: black;
  display: flex;
}

.menu-item-list .menu-item {
  background-color: orange;
}

.menu-item-list .menu-item .label {
  width: 57%;
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 50%;
}

.menu-item-list .menu-item .value {
  width: 43%;
}

.menu-item-list .menu-item.active.control-slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu-item-list .menu-item.active.control-slider .label {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-item-list .menu-item.active.control-slider .value {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em 1em 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<ol class="menu-item-list">
  <li id="menu-item-las-powr" class="menu-item control-slider active">
    <div class="label">Label</div>
    <div class="value">
      <div class="slider-view">
        <div class="slider-box">
          <div class="safe-slider">
            <div class="slider-val-line-parent">
              <div class="slider-val-text">
                BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO
                BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

---

You cannot use `absolute` positioning in `static` contexts and expect them to change the size of `static` elements. They are on an independent layer. If you wonder: `Static` elements are the default i.e. if you don't specify a position it is `position: static`.

The position attribute is crucial to understand. I suggest you read this [mdn article here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning).

I have used this [converter tool here](https://www.sassmeister.com) to convert your `SASS` code to `CSS` in order to provide a snippet.

Please let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```css
.menu-item-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  left: 1em;
  right: 40%;
}

.menu-item-list li {
  display: flex;
}

.menu-item-list .control-slider .value {
  padding: 0 1em 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu-item-list .control-slider .slider-view {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.menu-item-list .control-slider .slider-view .slider-val-line-parent {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  left: 0;
}

.menu-item-list .control-slider .slider-view .slider-val-line-parent .slider-val-text {
  flex: 1;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  justify-content: right;
}

.menu-item-list .control-slider .slider-box {
  padding: 0.1em 0.25em;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: purple;
  opacity: 50%;
}

.menu-item-list .control-slider .slider-box .safe-slider {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-item-list .control-slider .slider-box .safe-slider .slider-val-line-parent {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: black;
  display: flex;
}

.menu-item-list .menu-item {
  background-color: orange;
}

.menu-item-list .menu-item .label {
  width: 57%;
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 50%;
}

.menu-item-list .menu-item .value {
  width: 43%;
}

.menu-item-list .menu-item.active.control-slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu-item-list .menu-item.active.control-slider .label {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-item-list .menu-item.active.control-slider .value {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em 1em 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<ol class="menu-item-list">
  <li id="menu-item-las-powr" class="menu-item control-slider active">
    <div class="label">Label</div>
    <div class="value">
      <div class="slider-view">
        <div class="slider-box">
          <div class="safe-slider">
            <div class="slider-val-line-parent">
              <div class="slider-val-text">
                BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO
                BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO BOO
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Here is the SASS code. I have marked the modified lines with `(ADDED)` or `(REMOVED)` the other comments were already there.

```sass
.menu-item-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  left: 1em;
  right: 40%;

  li {
    display: flex;
  }

  .control-slider {
    .value {
      padding: 0 1em 0 0;
      box-sizing: border-box; // (ADDED)
    }

    .slider-view {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;

      .slider-val-line-parent {
        padding: 0;
        // height: 100%;
        text-align: right;
        // display: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap;
        // position: absolute; (REMOVED)
        left: 0;

        .slider-val-text {
          flex: 1;
          //width: calc(100% + 16px); (REMOVED)
          //right: 7px; (REMOVED)
          //position: relative; (REMOVED)
          //top: 36px; (REMOVED)
          padding-right: 0px;
          padding-left: 0px;
          font-size: 14px;
          justify-content: right;
          // height: auto;
        }
      }
    }

    .slider-box {
      //height: 1.5em; (REMOVED)
      padding: 0.1em 0.25em;
      width: 50%;
      //position: relative; (REMOVED)
      background-color: purple;
      opacity: 50%;

      .safe-slider {
        background-color: green;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%; // without this, slider fill disappears
        position: relative;

        .slider-val-line-parent {
          border-style: dashed;
          border-color: black;
          // display: inline-block;
          display: flex;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .menu-item {
    background-color: orange;
    // height: auto;
    .label {
      width: 57%;
      background-color: yellow;
      opacity: 50%;
    }
    .value {
      width: 43%;
    }
  }

  .menu-item.active.control-slider {
    // display: list-item;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    .label {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .value {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 1em 1em 1.5em;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting close . . . but need only the orange (outer) container to grow to include the dashed container and its contents (text). The other containers need to stay at the height they are.Thanks!

Comment: @user2132190 You cannot do that. The containers are dependent on each other they inherit the size constraints of the parent containers. If you don't want to change the other containers as well it means that the size of the orange container won't grow (a parent cannot be smaller than its child element). The only other way would be to make the child `position: absolute` - pretty much what you already have in this case you have to set the height of the orange container manually.

Comment: @user2132190 I have provided a workaround and a suggestion. Please have a look.

Comment: @FMuller I think that is a reasonable workaround, given that this is legacy code. Thank you so much!